# VBA get address of the matched cell not the value

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to capture the range/row or cell address of the match. As you can see in the last line of this snippet, the match and associated data is being copied from the source sheet to the recipient sheet. The problem I have realized is that the source i is not necessarily the correct row in the receiver.

```
Dim FindString As String
Dim Rng As Range
    FindString = wsSource.Range("B" & i).Value
    If Trim(FindString) <> "" Then
    With wsReciever.Range("A:A") 'searches all of column A
        Set Rng = .Find(What:=FindString, _
        After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), _
        LookIn:=xlValues, _
        LookAt:=xlWhole, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
        SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=False)
        If Not Rng Is Nothing Then  'value found copy hours to Total Wk
        'Estimates
        wsSource.Range("F" & i & ":" & "NS" & i).Copy _
        wsReceiver.Range("D" & ? & ":" & "NQ" & ?)
```

So is it possible to capture the address of the match in the recipient sheet so that I can paste the data into the correct row?

TIA.

Comment: Try using `Rng.Address` after `If Not Rng Is Nothing Then`. If you want the row, use `Rng.Row`

Comment: Hi Shai Rado, I would happily give you the check mark just for taking the time answer let alone being right :-)  I could do so if you had posted and answer instead of a comment.

Comment: Added my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go, following my comment above:

If you want to get the `Address` use `Rng.Address` after `If Not Rng Is Nothing`.

If you want to get the `Row` number, use `Rng.Row`.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry about this post, (RTFM) as soon as I posted it I found the answer.

you simple have to use range object of the search, in this case Rng and set a variable equal to its address when a match is found.

```
j = Rng.Address 'if you want the Cell or 
j = Rng.Row 'if you just need the row number.
```